# Python Data Frame if and for syntax error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

When I'm attempting to run the following command, I'm receiving a "invalid syntax" error which I have pasted below

Command:

```
Orig_df['Generation'] = [Val if x > LBY and x < UBY for x in ['birth_year']]
```

Error

```
    Orig_df['Generation'] = [Val if x > LBY and x < UBY for x in ['birth_year']]
                                                      ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I am unable to work out what I am doing wrong.

For clarity the ^ is pointed at the r on the for - I wasn't able to work out how to correct on here

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take another look at the syntax for [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

It looks like you're trying to write

```
Orig_df['Generation'] = [Val for x in ['birth_year'] if x > LBY and x < UBY]
```

Note that the filtering condition comes after the `for` it is associated with.

Do note that there are other issues with this code that will prevent it from running after your correct your list comprehension syntax.